# "Error: incompatible types" When Iterating Through TreeMap

Tags: java, loops, treemap

Overall, I am trying to create basically a search program using inverted indexes, TF-IDF, and other related topics.

I have a TreeMap, wordToPost, which maps a string to a Posting object.

```
// Map each term to a Posting object
Map<String, Posting> wordToPost = new TreeMap<String, Posting>();
```

Previously, a string, stemQuery, has been put into the above TreeMap with its corresponding Posting. I retrieve the Posting object for stemQuery and assign it to thisPosting:

```
// Get the posting object for this word
Posting thisPosting = wordToPost.get(query)
```

Then I take the thisPosting object and get its internal TreeMap, which is defined as:

```
// Map the document ID to the number of occurrences in that document
TreeMap<Integer, Integer> docToOccur = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

Getting the TreeMap:

```
TreeMap trMap = thisPosting.getMap();
```

Now I would like to iterate through each entry in trMap, so I do the following:

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : trMap.entrySet())
    {
       // Will do misc. operations here
    }
```

The error I get is on the for loop line. It says
required: Entry
found: Object
There is a little arrow that points to the first parenthesis on trMap.entrySet()

I understand that this is saying trMap.entrySet is evidently returning an Object, instead of the expected Entry, but I'm not sure how to fix this. How do I successfully iterate through this TreeMap?

Comment: `TreeMap trMap` is a raw-type. You should use `TreeMap<Integer, Integer> trMap`

Comment: @Tunaki, that fixed it!